# html page occupying 100% window size and always on the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

note: 1st of all dont worry about 1st part of the question, its meant as reference for 2nd part,

I was able to get the full window by using this:

```
window.open(getMe.getCand(), "_blank", "height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",top=0,left=0,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no")
```

Coming to 2nd part of my question: bottom portion of my page was covered by taskbar, How can I have my webpage always on the top?

Reason why I want this: I am trying to create a question,answer platform, so as soon as student open that page, I dont want him to see anything on the desktop except that page, basically to avoid any cheating

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can achieve this in a foolproof way using standard web browsers. Whether a window can go on top of the Windows start bar is an operating system setting available via right-clicking the start bar and selecting Properties (but I think in latest windows, they don't even have that setting any more).

Perhaps a better solution, if your target browser supports it, would be to use use the [HTML5 fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fullscreen Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#">Start</a>

    <script>
    // Find the right method, call on correct element
    function launchFullscreen(element) {
      if(element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
      } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
    }

    // Launch fullscreen for browsers that support it!
    document.querySelector("a").onclick = function() { launchFullscreen(document.documentElement); }; // the whole page
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that fullscreen cannot be triggered on page load - it has to be triggered by a user action, e.g. clicking a 'Start' button. Perhaps your window could start off just showing a start button, which triggers fullscreen and shows the Q&A.

However, there's no way to stop them pressing Escape to return to a normal window. Just as there's no way to stop them pressing Alt+F4 or Ctrl+Alt+Delete to close the browser window. Without custom presentation software you will not be able to limit that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to open new window, this will disable the address bar.

```
window.open(getMe.getCand(),"winname","height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350");
```

Firefox 3.0 and it's higher versions disabled setting location by default.
For further details refere [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open).